# Plotting large pandas data frame in 3D

Tags: python, pandas, matplotlib

I am currently trying to visualize a huge amount of data in the same plot. Basically, I have data in the interval [0,1] obtained between 13:00 and 16:00 with a 5 seconds interval. The data is stored in a pandas DataFrame, `DF`, having this 5-second-interval timestamp as index. So the data looks like

```
>>> DF

                 a         b         c
13:00:00  0.994035  0.996058  0.998792
13:00:05  0.994035  0.996058  0.998776
13:00:10  0.994061  0.996058  0.998768
13:00:15  0.994105  0.996058  0.998768
13:00:20  0.994070  0.996058  0.998761

...
```

Of course, the obvious way to go about the problem would be to just call pandas own plot-function `DF.plot()`, yielding [image: Plot showing data for a, b and c.]

But since I have an immense (hundreds) of such data it would not make any sense, and instead I thought of perhaps visualize it using a 3d-plot, where e.g. the

- x-axis is the timestamp (the index for the data frame above)
- y-axis is the column names of the data frame (in the example `a`, `b` and `c`, respectively), and
- z-axis is the actual data.

However, as I am not too familiar with plotting-techniques, I thought there could perhaps be someone out there who is.

Comment: Try the [matplotlib thumbnail gallery](http://matplotlib.org/gallery.html). It's my #1 stop whenever I'm wondering how to pull something off with matplotlib, and makes subsequent queries much narrower

Comment: Who you consider having an interactive plot, where you can zoom at a specific timestamp range to see the data? If so you can check out [Bokeh](http://bokeh.pydata.org/en/latest/docs/gallery/correlation.html)

Comment: Hundreds is not immense in Pandas, millions is ;-). You can certainly plot data in 3d like so:
http://matplotlib.org/examples/mplot3d/bars3d_demo.html
Do you have hundreds of columns you want to graph or just three columns with hundreds of points? That would change the implementation slightly

Comment: No, as you say there are several more columns. Thanks