# Plot data from large sparse numpy.ndarray in 3D bar plot with different array length

Tags: python, matplotlib, plot

My question is similar to this [question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/37336342/plot-spectroscopic-data-from-pandas-dataframe-in-3d-with-different-array-length) which I want to plot my spectroscopic data to 3D-plot but

1) My data is matrix in np.ndarray

2) It has a large dimension of 1201*5001 (`result.shape = (1201,5001)`), therefore the hard code labeling manually is not suitable.

3) The data is not continuous and sparse. The final plot may look like [mplot3d](https://matplotlib.org/mpl_toolkits/mplot3d/tutorial.html) bar3d.

Can I use 3D bar plot from Matplotlib in this case? If possible, how to define the different length for every axes?

---

This is my code in progress (3rd update)

```
if __name__ == '__main__':
from mpl_toolkits.mplot3d import Axes3D
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt
import matplotlib
%matplotlib inline

# from array, x is time, y is mz, z is intensity
# in graph x is mz, y is time, z is intensity

fig = plt.figure()
ax = fig.add_subplot(111, projection='3d')

zs = np.arange(0, 50.01, 0.01)

    for z in zs:
        xs = np.arange(300, 1500.01, 1)
        ys = result

        ax.bar(xs,ys,zs=z,zdir='y')

plt.show()
```

Error (3rd)

```
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "prelimnmf_importcsv3.py", line 70, in <module>
    ax.bar(xs,ys,zs=z,zdir='y')
  File "/Users/pp/anaconda/lib/python2.7/site-packages/mpl_toolkits/mplot3d/axes3d.py", line 2394, in bar
    patches = Axes.bar(self, left, height, *args, **kwargs)
  File "/Users/pp/anaconda/lib/python2.7/site-packages/matplotlib/__init__.py", line 1892, in inner
    return func(ax, *args, **kwargs)
  File "/Users/pp/anaconda/lib/python2.7/site-packages/matplotlib/axes/_axes.py", line 2115, in bar
    if h < 0:
ValueError: The truth value of an array with more than one element is ambiguous. Use a.any() or a.all()
```

Comment: What code have you tried so far?

Comment: @James I added my code, sorry. It has many errors. I try fixing it now.

Comment: So, you have 3-dimensial array (X,Y,Z) where Z are the values and you want to make a column-wise bar plot (for example along X), or what exactly are you trying to do? Also, if you are talking about sparse: Does this mean that a lof of points are neglectable? How about just entering NaN there? MPL should be able to ignore them.

Comment: Where is the difference to [the question you asked yesterday](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/43492992/how-to-define-the-third-axis-of-ndarray-3d-data-to-matplotlib)? There is also still the important information missing  how your data (`result`) is organized. Same thing here. Please  read and understand [mcve].

Comment: @alexblae Yes, Z is height. Thanks for mentioning about sparse. Now the plot is running but it is so slow. If I replace 0 (yes it can be neglected in the plot) with NaN, is the plot faster?

Comment: @ImportanceOfBeingErnest Yesterday I asked and used polycollection. Thanks for your comment so I know it can't do that. Here I found bar3d is more appropriate as the data is not continuous. 

My result data is np.ndarray with dimension 1201*5001 (result.shape = (1201,5001)). The question already has this info but if I'm wrong, may you specify more what should I write about how data is organized? Thank you so much.

Comment: @Jan It should make the plotting faster, since it will automatically ignore all NaN values and does not have to compute the histogram for all the ignored data.

Comment: @alexblae I added `ys[ys == 0] = 'nan'` before plot ax.bar. It can't be plotted. The error is `AttributeError: 'list' object has no attribute 'tolist' ` I guess it can't skip the NaN. Have you encountered this situation before?

Answer (score 1):

While I doubt that a bar plot with 1200*5000 can give any visual insight into the data, it should still be possible to use it.

So here is an example

```
from mpl_toolkits.mplot3d import Axes3D
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt
import numpy as np; np.random.seed(1)

#Assume you have arrays like this
x = np.arange(300,1500,100)
y = np.arange(4)*10
Z = np.random.rand(len(y), len(x))*33

fig = plt.figure()
ax = fig.add_subplot(111, projection='3d')

for i in range(len(y))[::-1]:
    c = plt.cm.jet(i/float(len(y)))
    ax.bar(x, Z[i,:], zs=y[i], zdir='y',  width=80,alpha=1 )

ax.set_xlabel('time')
ax.set_ylabel('mz')
ax.set_zlabel('intensity')

plt.show()
```

[image]